# What does the diamond Minecraft sword do?

Tags: the-talos-principle

I found a diamond Minecraft sword hidden in the back of the *Circumlocution* puzzle in C-6, but I couldn't find anything to use it on. Is there anything I can use it on? What can I do with it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. This is another easter egg.

I can't remember exactly, so just briefly. You can use it on a wall with plants on it to clear the wall from them and read QR code behind them.

Comment: Hah! I found that QR code but never found the sword to clear the plants away to read the code. I was convinced this was done on purpose just to mess with the player.